# Animate resizing a ListView item on tap

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a multi-line Text() inside a ListView item. 
By default I only want to show 1 line. When the user taps this item i want it to show all lines. I achieve this by setting the maxLines property of the Text-Widget dynamically to 1 or null.
This works great, but the resizing occurs immediatly but I want to animate this transition.

Here is some example code:

```
class ListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListItem();
        },
        itemCount: 3,
        separatorBuilder: (_, int index) => Divider(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  ListItem({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
  bool _expanded;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _expanded = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _expanded = !_expanded;
        });
      },
      child: Text(
        'Line1\nLine2\nLine3',
        maxLines: _expanded ? null : 1,
        softWrap: true,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
      ),
    );    
  }
}
```

I also already tried using an AnimatedSwitcher like this:

```
class ListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ListPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListItem();
        },
        itemCount: 3,
        separatorBuilder: (_, int index) => Divider(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  ListItem({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListItemState createState() => _ListItemState();
}

class _ListItemState extends State<ListItem> {
  bool _expanded;
  Widget _myAnimatedWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _expanded = false;
    _myAnimatedWidget = ExpandableText(key: UniqueKey(), expanded: _expanded);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _expanded = !_expanded;
          _myAnimatedWidget =
              ExpandableText(key: UniqueKey(), expanded: _expanded);
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        child: _myAnimatedWidget,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpandableText extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExpandableText({Key key, this.expanded}) : super(key: key);
  final expanded;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Line1\nLine2\nLine3',
      maxLines: expanded ? null : 1,
      softWrap: true,
      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
    );
  }
}
```

This animates the Text-Widget but the ListView-Row still resizes immediatly.

What is my mistake? Is the approach of setting the maxLines property maybe wrong for my problem?

Thanks for your help !

Have a great day !

Comment: Have you attempted to surround the whole widget with an animated container and change the height of it with the same tap of the user?

Comment: @JoãoSoares Thank you so much ! Your answer got me on the right track. With AnimatedContainer the animation worked fine, but since I have dynamic content I can't tell what size it should be. But I just found AnimatedSize which is exactly what I need ! Thank you very much for your answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Joao's comment I found the right answer:

I just had to wrap my Widget inside the AnimatedSize() widget. That's all :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your app!